# how to write API code to render background image in blender 2.8

Tags: python

I am new to blender and can't find any resources online that provides a snippet of python code that shows how to render background image in blender 2.8.

Can show one help please.

Thanks.

---

Background image means any jpg or png file to be used as background. Let's say I have an object in the scene with an jpg as a background image. How can my render output contains both the object and the scene?

Comment: Probably simply this https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=render#bpy.ops.render.render ... but could you add more details?

Comment: What's "background image"? How is it different from any other rendered image?  Why is it version 2.8? If you are new to Blender it probably makes no sense to use outdated version. How did you try to find it online? Google search for "bpy render image" returns plenty of results. You can also search the documentation of the API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=render&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: Background image means any jpg or png file to be used as background. Let's say I have an object in the scene with an jpg as a background image. How can my render output contains both the object and the scene?